# C# query DataTable by string with Arithmetic Operators in column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable name "Numb" and column name "ColA" and "ColB".
like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Numb");  
dt.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("ColB", typeof(Int32));
dt.Rows.Add(1, 2);
dt.Rows.Add(3, 4);
dt.Rows.Add(5, 6);
```

I would like to
ColA+2, ColB*3
by creating strings like this:

```
string strSQL = "Select " + "(ColA+2), " + "(ColB*3)  " +"from Numb";
```

Can I query DataTable dt by strSQL?

(I would like to query by using a string

because I can adjust amount of columns as I want

if it has more two column, I can choose to use some columns

and I can calculate the columns by arithmetic operators as I want,

just by creating a string variable.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => (x.Field<Int32>("ColA") + 2) + (x.Field<Int32>("ColB") * 3) )

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for answering. How can I vary amount of columns if I have more two columns? I want to use strings because I want to adjust amount of columns.

Comment: dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray.Select((y, i) => y).ToArray()).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an SQL query on DataTable this is not a good idea and it will cost your project performance.

**Possible Solutions:**

- You can use an extension method like DataTable.Select
- Or you can use Linq extensions to perform your desire result.